# PHP write to email problem

Tags: php

I have the following script which creates an email from a contact form:
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1b54

I am having trouble getting the contents of the 'heard' drop down list (line 49) to output to the email.

I can successfully output the selected value on line 99 but when i try to add it to the email on line 131 nothing appears. I get the Heard: but not the actual value.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly - $heard is a global variable that is defined on line 88 so it is not avaliable inside a function. Change

```
global $to, $extra;
```

to

```
global $to, $extra, $heard;
```

this should help.

Upd: I think you should read about variable scopes in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php .